# Visual studio 2010 and Windows embedded standard 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-embedded, windows-embedded-standard

I'm trying Windows Embedded Standard 7 and I'm having some problem with Matrox in my program and I would  like to debug it with Visual Studio 2010. I installed Visual Studio 2010 professional but every time I try to open a file it crash with this pop pop : "Unknow Hard Error" with a "OK" button and everything close ( Visual Studio ) when I click on the "OK".
In the Event viewer I found an error in "Application" :

> Source: .NET Runtime
>   Event ID : 1025

I am not sure if I need to add an other feature pack to my Windows Embedded installation or if the problem come from something else ?
Thank you!

Comment: You ought to get used to the Remote Debugger when you troubleshoot an embedded system.

Comment: Oh, thanks!
I never used the Remote Debugger..